# upload mp3 audio file from ipod library to remote server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

Is it possible to upload mp3 audio file from ipod library to remote server?

I want to upload a song directly from ipod to reomote server using PHP script, I can access songs library using MPMediaPicket but unable to form a NSData request through it?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.
audios from iPod Library are protected and you can only access through limit apis that provided by apple.

Answer (score 2):

Only AV Foundation Can access ipod library,So,You can use AVAssetReader + AVAssetWriter　to export the music from ipod library to Your document ,then u can r/w it and do anything.

U　can reference this QAs:
1.
[Extract iPod Library raw PCM samples and play with sound effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796643/extract-ipod-library-raw-pcm-samples-and-play-with-sound-effects).
2.
http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/07/19/from-iphone-media-library-to-pcm-samples-in-dozens-of-confounding-potentially-lossy-steps/
3.
http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/